# Merge Join Transformation - Matching Multiple Columns

Tags: ssis

I Have two OLE DB Data Sources. one has the columns

ID,
Premium

and the other has

ID,
Premium,
Cost

They are both in the same data flow and both sorted.

I use them both as a source for a Merge Join Transformation. I have told it that both ID and Premium are the ones to match on.

I was hoping for the output of this merge join to be ONLY rows where both ID and Premium both match. Instead what i seem to be getting is rows which match EITHER Id or Premium.

It is set to be an Inner Join as i dont want to get columns with Nulls / non matches in hanging around.

Does anyone know how to achieve the desired output? Am I using the right Transformation tool to achieve this?

Comment: You should use the Lookup transformation and lookup the Cost and map only the matched output to the destination table. Hope this helps!

Comment: Exactly what @Gowdhaman008 said. Unless you have a reason to use the `Merge Join Transformation`, you will get better performance out of your package by using the `Lookup Transformation`. And on the off chance that both OLE DB Sources are in the same database and/or instance, just write an inner join and let the database handle it. It'll be far more efficient than SSIS as it can take advantage of existing indexes while SSIS will have to build it in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the correct transformation. However, by default the merge join transformation treats NULL values as equal. You can turn this off by setting the `TreatNullsAsEqual` property of the transformation to false. This way, you should get the same result as a regular SQL query.